# Error with my htaccess redirect matching incorrect URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, query-string

Here are the redirects in my htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^project/(.*)$ /service/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} name
RewriteRule ^$ /? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} p
RewriteRule ^$ /? [R=301,L]
```

The problem I'm having is that it is interfering with a particular url.

Instead of getting:

http://www.example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?gf_page=select_columns&id=1&TB_iframe=true&height=365&width=600

I'm getting:

http://www.example.com/?gf_page=select_columns&id=1&TB_iframe=true&height=365&width=600

I see that the url parameter has the word "page" in it.

I'm wondering if my redirect is not an exact match, and therefore matching the "p" in the word "page".

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} p
```

If that is (in fact) the problem, how can I make the query_string an exact match?

That rewrite condition is supposed to only grab query strings from the root level of the domain that match exactly with p.

If that is not the problem, any other ideas?

Comment: does your query string start with a p or is just p=?

Comment: there are many urls that i need to redirect such as:
example.com?p=32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this and also combine the two rules. That should help just matching p.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (name|p)=.+
RewriteRule ^$ /? [R=301,L]
```

Clear you cache before trying new rules because of the previous 301's you set.

Comment: Thank you!  That not only works, but it has trimmed down a few lines in my htaccess file.